# Fraction Calculator in android

Tags: android, calculator

I want to Implement Proper and Improper Fractions calculation feature along with basic functionality of calculator in an android project and Display output for improper fractions. I have a basic calculator working but need help in function implementation.

The Code for simple/basic calculator is
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonOne,buttonTwo,buttonThree,buttonFour,buttonFive,buttonsix,buttonsevn,buttonEight,buttonNine;
Button buttonPlus,buttonMinus,buttonDivide,buttonMultiply,buttonEqual,buttonClean;
public String str ="";
Character op = 'q';
int i,num,numtemp;
TextView showResult;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    buttonTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    buttonThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button3);
    buttonFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button4);
    buttonFive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button5);
    buttonsix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button6);

    buttonEight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button8);
    buttonNine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button9);
    buttonPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonplus);
    buttonMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonminus);
    buttonMultiply= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonmulti);
    buttonDivide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondivide);
    buttonEqual = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonequal);
    buttonClean = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonclear);
    showResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_id);


}
  public void button1Clicked(View v){
      insert(1);

  }

public void button2Clicked(View v){
      insert(2);

  }
  public void button3Clicked(View v){
      insert(3);

  }
  public void button4Clicked(View v){
      insert(4);

  }
  public void button5Clicked(View v){
      insert(5);

  }
  public void button6Clicked(View v){
      insert(6);
  }
  public void button7Clicked(View v){
      insert(7);

  }
  public void button8Clicked(View v){
      insert(8);

  }
  public void button9Clicked(View v){
      insert(9);

  }
  public void buttonplusClicked(View v){
      perform();
      op = '+';

  }

public void buttonminusClicked(View v){
      perform();
      op = '-';

  }
  public void buttondivideClicked(View v){
      perform();
      op = '/';

  }
  public void buttonmultiClicked(View v){
      perform();
      op = '*';

  }
  public void buttonequalClicked(View v){
      calculate();

  }

public void buttonclearClicked(View v){
      reset();
  }
  private void reset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     str ="";
     op ='q';
     num = 0;
     numtemp = 0;
     showResult.setText("");
}
private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      str = str+Integer.toString(j);
      num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
      showResult.setText(str);


}
  private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
}
  private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(op == '+')
        num = numtemp+num;
    else if(op == '-')
        num = numtemp-num;
    else if(op == '/')
        num = numtemp/num;
    else if(op == '*')
        num = numtemp*num;
    showResult.setText(""+num);
}
```

}

Comment: For help, you would need to post a specific question with relevant code and error messages if they apply. See [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions.

Comment: We have code now...getting closer. But you still haven't asked a question.

Comment: want to do operations on fraction and get output for improper functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic functional calculator code in Java suitable for Android smartphones:

/**

- A basic calculator app for Android
  */

public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView resultTextView;
private Button buttonZero, buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive, buttonSix, buttonSeven, buttonEight, buttonNine, buttonAdd, buttonSub, buttonMul, buttonDiv, buttonDot, buttonC, buttonEqual;
private String result, operator;
private double operand1, operand2, answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    // Initialize the UI elements
    resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_textview);
    buttonZero = findViewById(R.id.button_zero);
    buttonOne = findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    buttonTwo = findViewById(R.id.button_two);
    buttonThree = findViewById(R.id.button_three);
    buttonFour = findViewById(R.id.button
```